# Remove partial array in Python

Tags: arrays, list

There is a 3 dimension list.

```
a = [[[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4]], [[4, 5], [5, 6], [6, 7]], [[7, 8], [8, 9], [9, 10]], [[10, 11], [11, 12], [12, 13]]]
```

so,

```
a[0][0][1] is 2

a[0][1][1] is 3

a[0][2][1] is 4

a[1][0][1] is 5

a[1][1][1] is 6

a[1][2][1] is 7
```

...

If I want to remove of particular element, such as  `a[:][:][1]`

I haved tried that

> > a.pop([0][0][1])

Tnen, Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
a[0][0].pop(1)
```

Given the list `a` in your question this would pop the number 2 from the list and `a` would look like this:

```
>>>a = [[[1], [2, 3], [3, 4]], [[4, 5], [5, 6], [6, 7]], [[7, 8], [8, 9], [9, 10]], [[10, 11], [11, 12], [12, 13]]]
```

See the note in the [Python list.pop documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.1/tutorial/datastructures.html).

It says:

> The square brackets around the i in the method signature denote that
>   the parameter is optional, not that you should type square brackets at
>   that position. You will see this notation frequently in the Python
>   Library Reference